# Gesture recognizer does not recognise a view which is created over an UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, redaction

I have an UIImageview with tap gesture on it, such that any tap over it creates a rectangular view with white background. Which I can move any where over imageview. Like this I can create infinite views over that imageview.

Now my problem is that I want to add double tap gestures to newly created views but when I click on any of those views then a new view is created over that view.

But what I want is that if I tap on a view then no new view must be created over that view.
Currently gestureRecognizer recognises UIImageView even if I have created a new view over UIImageView.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow share some code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ImageView,

```
UIImageView  *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];
UITapGestureRecognizer * tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(createNewView)];
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1]; // allow to create new view

UITapGestureRecognizer * tapRecognizerToFail = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]init];
[tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:2]; // to disallow more than 1 tap.

[tapRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:tapRecognizerToFail];
 [imageView setGestureRecognizers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:tapRecognizer,tapRecognizerToFail,nil]];
```

// New View Creation over ImageView

```
-(void)createNewView
{
    UIView  * view = [[UIView alloc]init];
    UITapGestureRecognizer * tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self action:@selector(newViewAction)];
    [tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
    [view addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

    [imageView addSubview:view];
}
```

// Double tap action over newly created view

```
-(void)newViewAction
{
 // goes here
}
```

Comment: thanx for ur help...i Got it right..but sorru can't rate u up as i dont have enough reputation..Tx a lot again...

Answer (score 0):

You can use requireGestureRecognizerToFail: to declare a dependency between your two recognizers.

```
[secondaryGesture requireGestureRecognizerToFail:primaryGesture];
```